# NullPointerException on Extending a Custom Activity

Tags: android

Have a DashBoardActivity that extends a custom MainActivity but i get NullPointerException when trying to access certain views from the DashBoardActivity. Any idea why this could be happening or something am not seeing here?. Thanks

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_layout);

        linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer_container_id);
        actionlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_container_id);

        mainboard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_dashboard_id);
        dashboard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_comparison_id);
        graph = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_graph_id);
        contact = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_contact_id);

        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
        actionbar.setCustomView(actionbarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 

        }

public void setSelectedDashBoard(){  
   mainboard.setSelected(true);
}
```

DashBoardActivity:

```
public class DashBoardActivity extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        sessionmanager = new SessionManager(this);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        String cached_username = prefs.getString(USERNAME, "");

        mainboard.setSelected(true);  // NullPointerException here.
```

dashboard_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/footer_container_id" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> 

    <include layout="@layout/footer"></include>   
    </LinearLayout>

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_fragment_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer_container_id"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

part of footer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer_id" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#292929" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ytd_container_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_dashboard_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/footer_icons_ytd" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/ytd_text_id" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="false" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:text="Year to Date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="10sp">

        </TextView>
        "
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
if i use the method setSelectedDashBoard() instead, which i just added from the MainActivity class, i don't get the NullPointerException. don't understand it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typical error of subclass member variable obscuration. You should check if you re-declared the variable dashboard in DashBoardActivity. The subclass is just substituting the inherited variable with a local one which is not initialised.

Answer (score 1):

```
  dashboard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_comparison_id);
```

the only reason for dashboard to be null is `R.id.image_comparison_id` does not belongs to `R.layout.dashboard_layout`

Comment: but its with the include tag in my layout. i will post my layout so you see.

Comment: logout.setOnClickListener(this) seems to be never initialized

Comment: my apologies.. i was trying to post only the relevant code and mixed things up. i have corrected my post accordingly.

Comment: wait, help me to understand. have You  declared a class variable named mainboard both in  MainActivity and DashBoardActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the character " , unless it is a typo.

```
   </TextView>
    **"**
 </LinearLayout>
```